# losing bottom border on pixel with decimal width value (firefox only)

Tags: html, css

I have an image within an image div container. I vertical and horizontal align it. But when i do so using transform - i lose the bottom border of one of my images, and am not quite sure why.

[image: ex]

**html:**

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img class="myImage" src='x'> 
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.imageContainer {
   width: 20px;
   max-height: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   position: relative;
   background-color: lightblue;
   }

.myImage { 
   width: auto;
   height: auto; /* Set to 9.2px in fiddle example to force the problem. */
   max-height: 25px;
   max-width: 20px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     
   }
```

**update:**
The reason for this is that the auto sized image land on a decimal value. (fx 9.2px) which is rounded down. So as I understand it, it wraps my 9.2 height element in a border and then rounds it down to 9px which makes the bottom border vanish. (even with `overflow: visible`)

Anyway to force auto values not to land on a decimal value? or something along those lines.

*fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/dLLan/24/ (the problem only happens in firefox, so make sure to run the fiddle in firefox.)*

Comment: Can you show us a demo? I can't see anything with the code that will make you lose the bottom border. Also, is the problem seen in all browsers or only in a certain browser (and version)?

Comment: Are you missing some transform? Because this way nothing happens, wat do you need to accomplish?

Comment: only happens in firefox (tested in newest stable version.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you updated your question, here is what I did:

1. Added a new div (`#imgholder`) to hold the `myImg` div.
2. Added the customized *width* and *height* of `20px` and `25px` on `#imgholder`. 
3. Changed *width* and *height* of `#myImage` to   `height: auto;` & `width: 100%;` to make it fit comfy on `#imgholder`.

```css
#imageContainer {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#imgholder {
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
}
#myImage {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="imgholder">
    <img id="myImage" src="http://s7.postimg.org/k8e5116ff/806c278b5a0f77b98f4dcc469f2d0b08.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just figured out the reason why the bottom border disappear is because my image is width and height is set to auto, in the size autos to 9.2 which gets rounded down to 9. - it puts an border around my 9.2 height element and then round it down to 9 which makes the bottom border vanish :/

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day, sometimes it just takes multiple looks into your code before you post a question(:

Comment: still confused on how to deal with it. Images with below something.4px value looses its bottom border. - elements getting rounded up is no problem.

Comment: Can you provide all of the parents within these divs and the full code so that we can see further into the problem?

Comment: check the fiddle example i just added. http://jsfiddle.net/dLLan/24/ thanks for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome, again, what is your issue because your bottom-border seems to be showing?

Comment: which browser are you viewing in it ? - i'm on firefox, and for me the bottom border is not visible in the fiddle example. in chrome its fine.

Comment: I was on Chrome and everything seems fine, but downloaded firefox just to check it out, I tested it and height: 9.3 seems to be your problem. I edited my answer, try it again.

Comment: the problem is i get that value from 'auto' because i dont want to scale the img wrong- so i have a container where the img can auto adjust width and height witin the parents attr, and every image that lands on .1 .2 .3 .4 will get rounded down. Anyway to avoid rounding down/up or forcing full integer values to start out with?

Comment: not sure how it fixes the problem, the  height can still hit a subpixel value, (9.2) which will make the bottom border vanish :/

Comment: What is .1 .2 .3 .4?

Comment: poorly explained sorry. I mean if the auto generated width hits a value with a decimal number below 5. (fx 9.3 will be rounded down to 9)